# trying to add a Custom ListView With an Adapter to a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm trying to add a **Custom ListView** With an **Adapter** to a **Fragment.**
I don't Know where is the problem exactly, I think I got everything in place yet I cant get rid of the **Unfortunately Stopped** message.
I Used the debug and knew where it all collapses ;

in the **Fragment** class at the

`for (int i = 0;i<4;i++){
.
.
.
questions.add(question);`

when the debug reaches this statement it ends.

**Fragment**

```
import java.util.List;

import code.me.R.id;
import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment 
{
    ListView lv;
    List<Question> questions;
    Integer[] Q_Id ;
    String[] AskerUserName =   {"Jack"      ,"John"    ,"Lio"      ,"Sam"         ,"Mike"        };
    String[] AnswererUserName ={"Jacob"     ,"Mario"   ,"Tom"      ,"Shon"        ,"Jasmine"     };
    String[] Qusetion =        {"What?"     ,"Where?"  ,"When"     ,"How?"        ,"Who?"        };
    String[] Answer =          {"jjjjjjjjjj","llllllll","fffffffff","eeeeeeeeeeee","oooooooooooo"};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        for (int i = 0;i<4;i++){
            int qid =  i;
            String AUName = AskerUserName[i].toString();
            String AnUName = AnswererUserName[i].toString();
            String Ans = Answer[i].toString();
            String Ques = Qusetion[i].toString();
            Question question = new Question(qid, AUName, AnUName, Ans, Ques);
            questions.add(question);


        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
        QuestionsAdapter questad = new QuestionsAdapter(getActivity(),questions);
        lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(questad);


        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.frag1, 
            container, false );
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
    import java.util.List;



import code.me.R.id;
import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Activity context;
    public List<Question> questions;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public QuestionsAdapter(Activity context,List<Question> qu) {


        this.context = context;
        this.questions = qu;



        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view , ViewGroup parent){
        View rowView = view;
        if(view == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_answer_item, null,false);
        TextView askerUserName = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.askerUsername);
        askerUserName.setText(questions.get(position).getAskerUserName().toString());
        TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.Question);
        question.setText(questions.get(position).getQuestion().toString());
        TextView ratingView = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.RatingAsker);
        //ratingView.setText(questions.get(position)._RatingU);
        TextView ratingAnswerer = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.RatingAnswerer);
        //ratingAnswerer.setText(questions.get(position).getRatingView());

        return rowView;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return questions.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return questions.get(position)._QId;
    }



}
```

**Class_Question**

```
    public class Question {

    private

     String _Answer ;
     String _AnswererUserName;
     String _AskerUserName ;
     String _Question ;
     Integer _QId;
     Integer _RatingU;
     Integer _RatingQ;

    public Question (int Q_Id,String AUName,String AnUName,String  Ans,String Ques){
        _QId = Q_Id;
        _AnswererUserName = AnUName;
        _AskerUserName = AUName;
        _Answer = Ans;
        _Question = Ques;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _Answer;
    }


    public String getAnswererUserName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _AnswererUserName;
    }


    public String getAskerUserName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _AskerUserName;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _Question;
    }


    public int getRatingView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _RatingU;
    }


    public void setRatingQ() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public int getRatingQ() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _RatingQ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize the `List<Question> questions` in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize your question collection. That's why it stops when you try to add questions in onCreateView. Either initialize List questions initially or some time before you try to add things to it.

Comment: Adding the line `List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();` did the trick,

Comment: I'm still having trouble adding a ListView /w Custom Item XML , any suggestions where to look , I have read things about using ListFragment and changing the @id in XML but still Fragment1 is not displaying the list